# Regex to Extract Numerical Value between string match

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I have a character vector that can in certain cases contain multiple examples where the following regular expressions are followed by a numeric value and then closed.  Here is an example:

```
form4_2  <- "<transactionPricePerShare><value>31.43</value>"
```

I'd like to be able to collect the "31.43" and any other numeric values between other examples of matching string contained in the character vector and then create a data frame with the result.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
library('stringr')
form4_3 <- form4_2[which(str_detect(form4_2,"</transactionPricePerShare>")=='TRUE')-1]
form4_3 <- str_remove(form4_3,'<value>')
form4_3 <- str_remove(form4_3,'</value>')
form4_4 <- data.frame(as.numeric(form4_3))
colnames(form4_4) <- "Transacted Price ($)"
```

#### Updated dput

```
"<SEC-DOCUMENT>0001179110-20-004802.txt : 20200408<SEC-HEADER>0001179110-20-004802.hdr.sgml : 20200408<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20200408162604ACCESSION NUMBER:\t\t0001179110-20-004802CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:\t4PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:\t\t1CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT:\t20200406FILED AS OF DATE:\t\t20200408DATE AS OF CHANGE:\t\t20200408REPORTING-OWNER:OWNER DATA:COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:\t\t\tSTAFFORD JOHN S IIICENTRAL INDEX KEY:\t\t\t0001218981FILING VALUES:FORM TYPE:\t\t4SEC ACT:\t\t1934 ActSEC FILE NUMBER:\t001-36182FILM NUMBER:\t\t20782220MAIL ADDRESS:STREET 1:\t\t230 SOUTH LASALLE STREET 400CITY:\t\t\tCHICAGOSTATE:\t\t\tILZIP:\t\t\t60604ISSUER:COMPANY DATA:COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:\t\t\tXencor IncCENTRAL INDEX KEY:\t\t\t0001326732STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION:\tPHARMACEUTICAL PREPARATIONS [2834]IRS NUMBER:\t\t\t\t201622502STATE OF INCORPORATION:\t\t\tDEFISCAL YEAR END:\t\t\t1231BUSINESS ADDRESS:STREET 1:\t\t111 WEST LEMON AVECITY:\t\t\tMONROVIASTATE:\t\t\tCAZIP:\t\t\t91016BUSINESS PHONE:\t\t626-305-5900MAIL ADDRESS:STREET 1:\t\t111 WEST LEMON AVECITY:\t\t\tMONROVIASTATE:\t\t\tCAZIP:\t\t\t91016</SEC-HEADER><DOCUMENT><TYPE>4<SEQUENCE>1<FILENAME>edgar.xml<DESCRIPTION>FORM 4 -<TEXT><XML><?xml version=1.0?><ownershipDocument><schemaVersion>X0306</schemaVersion><documentType>4</documentType><periodOfReport>2020-04-06</periodOfReport><notSubjectToSection16>1</notSubjectToSection16><issuer><issuerCik>0001326732</issuerCik><issuerName>Xencor Inc</issuerName><issuerTradingSymbol>XNCR</issuerTradingSymbol></issuer><reportingOwner><reportingOwnerId><rptOwnerCik>0001218981</rptOwnerCik><rptOwnerName>STAFFORD JOHN S III</rptOwnerName></reportingOwnerId><reportingOwnerAddress><rptOwnerStreet1>350 N. ORLEANS STREET</rptOwnerStreet1><rptOwnerStreet2>SUITE 2N</rptOwnerStreet2><rptOwnerCity>CHICAGO</rptOwnerCity><rptOwnerState>IL</rptOwnerState><rptOwnerZipCode>60654-1975</rptOwnerZipCode><rptOwnerStateDescription></rptOwnerStateDescription></reportingOwnerAddress><reportingOwnerRelationship><isDirector>0</isDirector><isOfficer>0</isOfficer><isTenPercentOwner>1</isTenPercentOwner><isOther>0</isOther><officerTitle></officerTitle><otherText></otherText></reportingOwnerRelationship></reportingOwner><nonDerivativeTable><nonDerivativeTransaction><securityTitle><value>Common Stock</value></securityTitle><transactionDate><value>2020-04-06</value></transactionDate><transactionCoding><transactionFormType>4</transactionFormType><transactionCode>S</transactionCode><equitySwapInvolved>0</equitySwapInvolved></transactionCoding><transactionAmounts><transactionShares><value>44771</value></transactionShares><transactionPricePerShare><value>31.84</value><footnoteId id=F1/></transactionPricePerShare><transactionAcquiredDisposedCode><value>D</value></transactionAcquiredDisposedCode></transactionAmounts><postTransactionAmounts><sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction><value>1206005</value></sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction></postTransactionAmounts><ownershipNature><directOrIndirectOwnership><value>I</value></directOrIndirectOwnership><natureOfOwnership><value>By Ronin Trading, LLC</value></natureOfOwnership></ownershipNature></nonDerivativeTransaction><nonDerivativeTransaction><securityTitle><value>Common Stock</value></securityTitle><transactionDate><value>2020-04-06</value></transactionDate><transactionCoding><transactionFormType>4</transactionFormType><transactionCode>S</transactionCode><equitySwapInvolved>0</equitySwapInvolved><footnoteId id=F2/></transactionCoding><transactionAmounts><transactionShares><value>600000</value></transactionShares><transactionPricePerShare><value>27.10</value><footnoteId id=F2/></transactionPricePerShare><transactionAcquiredDisposedCode><value>D</value></transactionAcquiredDisposedCode></transactionAmounts><postTransactionAmounts><sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction><value>606005</value></sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction></postTransactionAmounts><ownershipNature><directOrIndirectOwnership><value>I</value></directOrIndirectOwnership><natureOfOwnership><value>By Ronin Trading, LLC</value></natureOfOwnership></ownershipNature></nonDerivativeTransaction></nonDerivativeTable><derivativeTable></derivativeTable><footnotes><footnote id=F1>This transaction was executed in multiple trades at prices ranging from $31.48 to $32.30. The price reported above reflects the weighted average purchase price. The reporting person hereby undertakes to provide upon request to the SEC staff, the issuer or a security holder of the issuer full information regarding the number of shares and prices at which the transactions were effected.</footnote><footnote id=F2>The transaction was executed in a single, privately negotiated transaction with an institutional buyer.</footnote></footnotes><ownerSignature><signatureName>/s/ John S. Stafford, III</signatureName><signatureDate>2020-04-08</signatureDate></ownerSignature></ownershipDocument></XML></TEXT></DOCUMENT></SEC-DOCUMENT>"
```

Comment: The code is incomplete.  It uses variables that are not defined and functions from packages without corresponding library statements.  Posts to SO should follow the instructions at the top of the  [tag:r]  tag page.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck clearly, `form4_2` is the only string referenced, and the `str_` are from `stringr`, are we really defending being this anal today? should we close a question when editing two lines makes the code reproducible?

Comment: If you answer a lot of questions you will appreciate the rules. The alternative is misunderstandings and moving the effort from the questioner to those answering even though the questioner could put in the effort to do it properly.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck today you became a hero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE in response to multiple comments:**

You can extract the price using `str_extract_all`, positive lookbehind `(?>=...)` as well as lookahead `(?=...)`, store the result in a vector and use the vector as a column in a dataframe:

```
Transacted_price <- str_extract_all(form4_2, 
                    "(?<=(<transactionPricePerShare><value>))\\d+\\.\\d+(?=(</value>))")
df <- data.frame(unlist(Transacted_price))
```

Result:

```
df
  unlist.Transacted_price.
1                    31.43
```

Data:

```
form4_2 <- "<SEC-DOCUMENT>0001179110-20-004802.txt : 20200408<SEC-HEADER>0001179110-20-004802.hdr.sgml : 20200408<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20200408162604ACCESSION NUMBER:\t\t0001179110-20-004802CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:\t4PUBLIC DOCUMENT COUNT:\t\t1CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT:\t20200406FILED AS OF DATE:\t\t20200408DATE AS OF CHANGE:\t\t20200408REPORTING-OWNER:OWNER DATA:COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:\t\t\tSTAFFORD JOHN S IIICENTRAL INDEX KEY:\t\t\t0001218981FILING VALUES:FORM TYPE:\t\t4SEC ACT:\t\t1934 ActSEC FILE NUMBER:\t001-36182FILM NUMBER:\t\t20782220MAIL ADDRESS:STREET 1:\t\t230 SOUTH LASALLE STREET 400CITY:\t\t\tCHICAGOSTATE:\t\t\tILZIP:\t\t\t60604ISSUER:COMPANY DATA:COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:\t\t\tXencor IncCENTRAL INDEX KEY:\t\t\t0001326732STANDARD INDUSTRIAL CLASSIFICATION:\tPHARMACEUTICAL PREPARATIONS [2834]IRS NUMBER:\t\t\t\t201622502STATE OF INCORPORATION:\t\t\tDEFISCAL YEAR END:\t\t\t1231BUSINESS ADDRESS:STREET 1:\t\t111 WEST LEMON AVECITY:\t\t\tMONROVIASTATE:\t\t\tCAZIP:\t\t\t91016BUSINESS PHONE:\t\t626-305-5900MAIL ADDRESS:STREET 1:\t\t111 WEST LEMON AVECITY:\t\t\tMONROVIASTATE:\t\t\tCAZIP:\t\t\t91016</SEC-HEADER><DOCUMENT><TYPE>4<SEQUENCE>1<FILENAME>edgar.xml<DESCRIPTION>FORM 4 -<TEXT><XML><?xml version=1.0?><ownershipDocument><schemaVersion>X0306</schemaVersion><documentType>4</documentType><periodOfReport>2020-04-06</periodOfReport><notSubjectToSection16>1</notSubjectToSection16><issuer><issuerCik>0001326732</issuerCik><issuerName>Xencor Inc</issuerName><issuerTradingSymbol>XNCR</issuerTradingSymbol></issuer><reportingOwner><reportingOwnerId><rptOwnerCik>0001218981</rptOwnerCik><rptOwnerName>STAFFORD JOHN S III</rptOwnerName></reportingOwnerId><reportingOwnerAddress><rptOwnerStreet1>350 N. ORLEANS STREET</rptOwnerStreet1><rptOwnerStreet2>SUITE 2N</rptOwnerStreet2><rptOwnerCity>CHICAGO</rptOwnerCity><rptOwnerState>IL</rptOwnerState><rptOwnerZipCode>60654-1975</rptOwnerZipCode><rptOwnerStateDescription></rptOwnerStateDescription></reportingOwnerAddress><reportingOwnerRelationship><isDirector>0</isDirector><isOfficer>0</isOfficer><isTenPercentOwner>1</isTenPercentOwner><isOther>0</isOther><officerTitle></officerTitle><otherText></otherText></reportingOwnerRelationship></reportingOwner><nonDerivativeTable><nonDerivativeTransaction><securityTitle><value>Common Stock</value></securityTitle><transactionDate><value>2020-04-06</value></transactionDate><transactionCoding><transactionFormType>4</transactionFormType><transactionCode>S</transactionCode><equitySwapInvolved>0</equitySwapInvolved></transactionCoding><transactionAmounts><transactionShares><value>44771</value></transactionShares><transactionPricePerShare><value>31.84</value><footnoteId id=F1/></transactionPricePerShare><transactionAcquiredDisposedCode><value>D</value></transactionAcquiredDisposedCode></transactionAmounts><postTransactionAmounts><sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction><value>1206005</value></sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction></postTransactionAmounts><ownershipNature><directOrIndirectOwnership><value>I</value></directOrIndirectOwnership><natureOfOwnership><value>By Ronin Trading, LLC</value></natureOfOwnership></ownershipNature></nonDerivativeTransaction><nonDerivativeTransaction><securityTitle><value>Common Stock</value></securityTitle><transactionDate><value>2020-04-06</value></transactionDate><transactionCoding><transactionFormType>4</transactionFormType><transactionCode>S</transactionCode><equitySwapInvolved>0</equitySwapInvolved><footnoteId id=F2/></transactionCoding><transactionAmounts><transactionShares><value>600000</value></transactionShares><transactionPricePerShare><value>27.10</value><footnoteId id=F2/></transactionPricePerShare><transactionAcquiredDisposedCode><value>D</value></transactionAcquiredDisposedCode></transactionAmounts><postTransactionAmounts><sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction><value>606005</value></sharesOwnedFollowingTransaction></postTransactionAmounts><ownershipNature><directOrIndirectOwnership><value>I</value></directOrIndirectOwnership><natureOfOwnership><value>By Ronin Trading, LLC</value></natureOfOwnership></ownershipNature></nonDerivativeTransaction></nonDerivativeTable><derivativeTable></derivativeTable><footnotes><footnote id=F1>This transaction was executed in multiple trades at prices ranging from $31.48 to $32.30. The price reported above reflects the weighted average purchase price. The reporting person hereby undertakes to provide upon request to the SEC staff, the issuer or a security holder of the issuer full information regarding the number of shares and prices at which the transactions were effected.</footnote><footnote id=F2>The transaction was executed in a single, privately negotiated transaction with an institutional buyer.</footnote></footnotes><ownerSignature><signatureName>/s/ John S. Stafford, III</signatureName><signatureDate>2020-04-08</signatureDate></ownerSignature></ownershipDocument></XML></TEXT></DOCUMENT></SEC-DOCUMENT>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but option 1 produces this output on my end:  "000117911020004802.20200408000117911020004802..2020040820200408162604000117911020004802412020040620200408202004080001218981419340013618220782220123040060604000132673228342016225021231111191016626305590011119101641.41.0030642020040616116000132673200012189811350.1222606541975001020200406404477131.84112060052020040640260000027.102606005131.4832.30...2..20200408" and option 2 produces: Transacted_price "1.0"

Comment: Okay. And what is your expected output? Or, how can you describe the conditions that hold for the expected output? For example "I want to extract those numbers that  satisfy (i) condition A, (ii) condition B, (iii) conditon C, etc."

Comment: I would just like to extract into, in this case, two rows of a new data.frame with chronological prices (values).  I.e. 31.84 contained in row 1 and 27.10 in row 2.  If there were more than two transactions there would be additional rows.  Does that make sense?

Comment: No. How do I know which of the millions of numbers in your string are "prices"? You need to describe the pattern!

Comment: I did in the comments but here it is again:  <transactionPricePerShare><value>31.43</value>

Comment: So every price you want to extract has `<transactionPricePerShare><value>`on the left and `</value>`on the right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212649/discussion-between-js80-and-chris-ruehlemann).

Comment: What do mean by "yes, that's right."? Does this answer your question?

Comment: What I mean is that in response to your comment that every price I want to extract has <transactionPricePerShare><value> on the left and </value> on the right is a correct statement.

Comment: You got it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the accept. Do consider also clicking the upward triangle. It's been quite an effort.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract anything between `<value>` and `</value>`. you can wrap the result ins `as.double()` if you want actual numbers to work with.

```
text <- "<transactionPricePerShare><value>31.43</value>"

sub(".*<value>(.*)</value>.*","\\1",text)

"31.43"
```

**Edit**

This is pretty specific and can't easily be changed to get other variables.

```
PlacesFound <- gregexpr("<transactionPricePerShare>", form4_2)
ExtractedNumbers <-sapply(PlacesFound[[1]], function(x) as.numeric(substr(form4_2,x+33,x+37)))

> ExtractedNumbers
[1] 31.84 27.10
```

Comment: What is ValsToFind referencing?  You've created a variable and referenced the variable in the formula with which its being created?

Comment: `ValsToFind` extracts the line after any line that contains `<transactionPricePerShare>` from a list called `form4_2`. The second line is just that, a 2nd line (starts with `as.numeric(....`.

Comment: I'm not generating that result.  I'm starting with "form4_2" which is the character vector and getting these responses: Error in form4_2[grep(".*<transactionPricePerShare>.*", form4_2) + 1,  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions and Error in gsub(".*<value>(.*)</value>.*", "\\1", ValsToFind) : 
  object 'ValsToFind' not found

Comment: can you share `dput(form4_2)`

Comment: Its shared.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did not realise that your string is all in one line. I've change my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately all that the new script returned was NA's except for two instances which were "2604" and "406" after printing ExtractedNumbers